# Test $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(-1)^n \over n(\ln{n})^p}$ for conditional and absolute convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I test
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(-1)^n \over n(\ln{n})^p}$$
for conditional and and absolute convergence.

I am able to conclude about the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{1 \over n(\ln{n})^p}$ from the Cauchy condensation test. The series converges for $p>1$, so the original series converges absolutely for such $p$.

Now, I would like to check conditional convergence. Let's consider $a_n={1 \over n(\ln{n})^p}$ again. For $p\ge 0$ we have $a_n$ decreasing to $0$ and from the Leibniz criterion we get conditional convergence for $p>1$. My problem is, how do we approach conditional convergence for $p<0$? My sense is that we have to show the terms of the series are larger than the terms of any well-known divergent series for sufficiently large $n$, however, I can't find such a series.

Comment: For any $a > 0, p$ and for $n > N$ large enough : $n^{-a} (\ln n)^p$ decreases to $0$ i.e. $\sum_{n=N}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-a} (\ln n)^p$ is an alternated series and converges

Answer (score 4):

Let $p<0$ and then $s=-p$ so that $s>0$.  Now we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(\ln n)^s}n$$

We know that $\sum_{n=2}^N(-1)^n$ is bounded and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^s}n=0$ (you may evaluate with repeated L'Hospital's rule) and monotone for all $n=\lceil e^s\rceil$.

Thus, by the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), it converges.  Indeed, the alternating test will show it converges for any $s,p$.

It should also be clear that it is not absolutely convergent, as you may use comparison test to the harmonic numbers.

As a last note, your sum can be given by

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(\ln n)^s}n=-e^{-s\pi i}\eta^{(s)}(1)$$

which are fractional derivatives of the Dirichlet eta function evaluated at $1$.  If $s\in\mathbb N$, this can more simply be written as

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(\ln n)^s}n=(-1)^{s+1}\eta^{(s)}(1)$$

Comment: This is the problem I run into increasingly often - how do I show ${\ln{n} \over n} \to 0$ without L'Hospital' rule and its monotonicity from some point on, again, without the use of derivatives?

Comment: @Zelazny You could say that $$\ln(x):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}h\implies\ln(x)=\mathcal O(x^h)\ \forall\ h>0$$This definition comes from the antiderivative of $x^n$ for $n=-1$.

Comment: For $s>0$, the function monotonically decreases for $n\ge \lfloor e^s \rfloor +1$

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, I more or less hint at that in the first few lines.

Comment: I interpreted "somewhere around" to mean that it isn't exactly $\lfloor e^s\rfloor +1$.

Comment: Oh, well, whatever you wish, I just left a few parts for the OP to go through. @Dr.MV

Comment: Sure and +1 for the post.  One more thing that you might mention is that you tacitly appealed to Dirichlet's Test.

Comment: @Dr.MV Isn't the alternating test enough?

Comment: It is enough here.  But the condition of boundedness extends beyond $(-1)^n$ to show, for example, that $\sum \frac{\sin(n)}{n^a}$, $a>0$ converges.  The alternating series test does not facilitate with analysis of that series.

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh, I see what you mean.  Ha, my brain thought more towards the Dirichlet test, but I also saw the alternating test.  Silly me :D

Comment: So, perhaps add text referencing Dirichlet's Test along with more precision around the $n>e^s$ language.

Comment: @Dr.MV :P Added ( btw, what do you think about the Dirichlet eta function part when $s<0$? )

Comment: Are you sure that those are the fractional derivatives?  Clearly for integer $s$, the last statement is correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV pretty sure they can be done like that.

Comment: I mean, there's a post about $\sqrt{\ln1}+\sqrt{\ln2}+\dots$ being regularized into the half derivative of the Riemann zeta function at $s=0$...

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer 
to your comment
about showing that
${\ln{n} \over n} \to 0
$.

This is equivalent to
$n^{1/n} \to 1$.

This can be done with
Bernoulli's inequality
as follows:

$(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^n
\ge 1+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}
> \sqrt{n}
= n^{1/2}
$.

Raising to the
$2/n$ power,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}})^2
&\gt n^{1/n}\\
\text{or}\\
n^{1/n}
&\lt 1+2\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{n}\\
&\le 1+3\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\\
&\to 1\\
&\text{as }
n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$